# Call to a member function userdata() on null

Tags: php, codeigniter

please help me!I don't know how do . I need your help

```
Message: Call to a member function userdata() on null

Filename: /home/xxxxx/xxxxx.x.it/xxx/application/libraries/Auth.php

Line Number: 23
```

Backtrace:

( page)
Function: get_user

(controller) 
Function: _costruttor

```
    function get_user() {
    $name = $this->session->userdata('id');
    if ($name) {
    $this->obj->db->where("id",$this->obj->session->userdata("id"));
        $this->obj->db->where("ip",$this->obj->input->ip_address());
        $user= $this->obj->db->get("u_user")->row_array();
        if ($utente) {
            $this->user = $user;
        }
    }



class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
function _costruttor() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library("encrypt");
    $unlocked = array('login');
    $this->page->get_user();
    $this->load->driver('cache', array('adapter' => 'file', 'backup' => 'file'));
    if (!$this->page->get_user() AND ! in_array(strtolower(get_class($this)), $unlocked)) {
        $this->session->set_userdata('back_url', current_url());
        redirect('login/');
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is `_costruttor()`!?

Comment: in php 5 i had a function my_controller but in php7 i can't use function with same name of class

Comment: It should probably be `__construct` surely?

Comment: And then can i have function  __construct  { parent:. __construct  ){ ??

Comment: Yes, you can (and would often expect) to have `parent::__construct()` in your __construct.

Comment: Ok i update this . But I have a problem with this error

Answer (score 1):

I think you have forgot to include `session` library.

There are two ways to solve this:

**1) Include `session` library dynamically in your page.**

Insert this

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

Before the line.

```
$name = $this->session->userdata('id');
```

**2) Adding it in autoload libraries:Another way of doing this is:**

If you required it globally, include it in

`applications/config/autoload.php`

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');
```

Assuming that `database` and `session` are required globally.

Comment: Message: Call to a member function library() on null

 [[[[[same function ( get_user)]]]]]

Comment: Please try second approach described in my updated answer.

Comment: Message: Call to a member function get_user() on null

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite simple

```
Message: Call to a member function userdata() on null


Line Number: 23
```

Meaning, on line 23  of the file described above, you are doing something among these lines

```
$this->session->userdata(/* something goes inside here */);
```

Meaning `$this->session` is null (it is not instanciated or it doesnt exist in this context. You can confirm this by `var_dump($this->session)`followed by an `exit` and if it gives a null, you've found the trouble)